# htaccess config for slim php framework

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, slim

I use Slim php framework to build some action inside index.php page:
so this is the way I call my action:

index.php/action1

```
$app->get('/action1',function () use ($app){
            echo "this is action 1";
});
```

index.php/action2

```
$app->get('/action2',function () use ($app){
            echo "this is action 2";
});
```

Now I want my url become pretty , such as when type in **index/action1**

, it will redirect to **index.php/action1**
Please provide me the solution in creating htaccess to do that
Thank and best reagard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

user group to prefix your route

```
$app->group('/index', function () use ($app) {
    /**
     * Route GET /index/action1
     */
    $app->get('/action1',function () use ($app){
        echo "this is action 1";
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks .but this way hide "index" page. I want to reserve "index" name because in future, I want to add many other pages.